# Kivy - Parsing structure to widget

Tags: python, data-structures, kivy

I'm having issues with parsing a data structure to a widget in Kivy, which would then access the structure and be able to show a value on the screen be updated continuously via a clock interval (not sure of a better to do this yet).

I have highlighted the issues in the (non-working) code below:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from test import TestWidget

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        testStructTable = {'randomVal1': 1, 'testVal': 2, 'randomVal2': 3}

        # Issue here parsing the table like this?
        return TestWidget(testStructTable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.py**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class TestWidget(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, testStructTable, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Builder.load_file('test.kv')

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='MainScreen'))
        self.add_widget(sm)

        # Error accessing the table
        print self.testStructTable

        # Have the update_test_val continuously called
        #Clock.schedule_interval(MainScreen.update_test_val(testStructTable), 1 / 60)


class MainScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        testVal = NumericProperty(0)

    def update_test_val(self, testStructTable):
        # Get testVal from testStructTable
        # Something like:
        # self.testVal = testStructTable.testVal + 1 ?
        self.testVal = self.testVal + 1
```

**test.kv**

```
<MainScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: str(root.testVal)
            font_size: 80
```

My aim is to have the testVal constantly updating on the screen by accessing that data structure, however I am currently unable to achieve this, can you please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__` method you're passing `testStructTable` and then you're trying to access `self.testStructTable` which does not exist untill you explicitly make an assignment:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class TestWidget(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, testStructTable, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        print(testStructTable)
        self.testStructTable = testStructTable
        print(self.testStructTable)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        testStructTable = {'randomVal1': 1, 'testVal': 2, 'randomVal2': 3}
        # Issue here parsing the table like this?
        return TestWidget(testStructTable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: That's worked, thanks! Would you also be able to advise how to have that testVal constantly updating on the screen please?

Comment: Using properties combined with `kivy.clock` module is a correct approach for doing that. Properties in kivy implement the observator pattern so any change to them can be instantly reflected in your widgets. See [here](http://www.gurayyildirim.com.tr/kivy-course-5-properties-and-clock-definitions-1191.html) for an example.